# ggplot2's geom_bar() not showing default x axis ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

As a simple example I am going to use the diamonds data:

```
data(diamonds)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = clarity, y = carat, fill = cut)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

This will give me the following output, where the x axis is not annotated:

[image: missing x- and y-axis labels]

How do I make the values of the x- and y-axis appear? I have been searching wide and far and haven't yet found a solution...

For my real dataset, my x-axis values are discrete, and using scale_x_discrete() does not change the outcome.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine, I believe you must update `ggplot2` and start a new `R` session:

```
data(diamonds)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = clarity, y = carat, fill = cut)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Duck, Thank you for your answer! I have updated/reinstalled/... to try and solve the issue, but to no avail. Can you tell me what version of ggplot you're using (I am currently on 3.3.2)?

Comment: @Phintac have you started a new R Session? Cleared the workspace? You may have a global theme set

Comment: Hi @Phintac I am using `ggplot2_3.3.0`. Maybe it is an issue from the newest version of the package. You could try downloading from `CRAN` a previous version and using it. As you see I did not have troubles with axis.

Comment: @Tjebo, Yeah, you got a point there, one of my other packages interfered with ggplot! Thank you :)

Comment: @Phintac It is also what I said. Re starting `R` will remove other themes ;) Hope you got the result. It would be nice if you accept the answer.

Comment: @Duck sorry, I think I needed it a little more explicit for my dumb brain :D Just loaded all packages again. I have accepted your answer :D